# Using RESTFul Oracle APEX

Tags: mongodb, rest, oracle-apex, restful-url

I am building a mobile App using [Appery.io](http://appery.io/) platform which uses [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.com/) -based database. I need to link this DB to Oracle database and use APEX to design an interface such that users can query, update the mobile App DB from Oracle as well as Oracle DB can be updated from the mobile App.

In APEX, I use the URI with **GET** method:

```
https://api.appery.io/rest/1/db/collections/Outlet_Details/
```

And I add the header:

```
X-Appery-Database-Id
```

When I run the query in the APEX where I insert the Database-Id, APEX shows the table/collection *Outlet_Details* in JSON format. However, not the entire table is shown due to, I think, the length of CLOB type.

Now my main problem is I need to query this table/collection called *Outlet_Details* by a column named: *_id*. So when I use the following URI:

```
https://api.appery.io/rest/1/db/collections/Outlet_Details/1234
```

It returns the specific record that ha _id = 1234. However, I do not want to hardcode it. Instead, I need to have more like where condition such that I can query based on any column value (e.g. userId instead _id). The CURL command is as follows:

```
curl -X GET
-H "X-Appery-Database-Id: 544a5cdfe4b03d005b6233b9"
-G --data-urlencode 'where={"userId ": "1234"}'
https://api.appery.io/rest/1/db/collections/outlet_details/
```

My problem is how to insert such a command into APEX, specailly (where) part.

In this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkCvd6P8_OU), oracle database is used. Hence using where condition with =:DEP condition, and then bind it to a variable is pretty straightforward. However, I need to replicate this tutorial with my MongoDB.
The other question, which I guess would clarify a lot to me, in the aforementioned tutorial, there is a prefix URI that is by default APEX shema URI. Even when I insert different URI template, the resultant URI will append APEX to the one I inserted. How to build a service there using different URI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that APEX takes where condition as **encoded parameter** in the URL. Something like:

```
https://api.appery.io/rest/1/db/collections/Outlet_Details?where=%7B%22Oracle_Flag%22%3A%22Y%22%7D
```

The header is same and no input parameters.

This can be done from Application builder > New Application > Database > Create Application > Shared Componenets > Create > REST  and then start inserting the header, utl .. etc.

You can refer to this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) as a reference encoded URL